# Trouble Installing "xlsx"

Tags: java, r, excel

I am trying to install the package `xlsx` on rmarkdown and I am getting an error. This is the code I am trying to run:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(install.packages("xlsx", repos = 
"http://cran.rstudio.com/"), library(xlsx), install.packages("rJava", 
repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/"), library(rJava), 
install.packages("xlsxjars", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/"), 
library(xlsxjars))
```

And the error I get is:

```
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" 
instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
call: .jinit()
error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Quitting from lines 10-11 (Excel_Files.Rmd) 
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'xlsx'
Execution halted
```

I have searched here and there were a few suggestions but none seems to work. For example, I tried to update both java and my local rstudio environment. The are both 64-bit.

The package `xlsx` need `rJava` and `xlsxjars` to work here. I have tried to install `xlsx` on its own and it prompted me to install the other two, which I did. And I have also tried to install them separately, like in the code above. I am getting the same error. What do I do?

Comment: Make sure you have JDK installed on your system. Also very unusual to install package in `opt_chunk$set`. Would not use `library` within  `opt_chunk$set`  either

Comment: Installed JDK and it worked. Thanks ```@RichardTelford```!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set:
`Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME" = "C:\\Path to Java\\jreversion")`
in .RProfile in your project.
Package xlsx needs to know where your java installation is.
For building a package which uses xlsx, you need the java jdk.

Comment: And don't forget to use the correct R-version. If you have 64bit Java, you can use 64 bit R and the same for x86, when using package `xlsx`.

Comment: Thank you ```@shearer```! I did all you suggested and it worked.

Comment: Nice to hear! @RevoTesha